# Random capitalization in a sentence

Tags: legibility, capitalization

A writer for one of the company websites is fond of randomly capitalising words in their content, which they say is for emphasis.

I have never seen this before and I don't like it. My gut tells me that anybody reading their content is going to be tripped up by finding capital letters where they don't expect them (like I was).

I am looking for supporting evidence for this please? I don't want to shut them down just because I think it looks silly. I want to back it up with evidence.

Examples:

> At Company Name We make sure that your International transition is seamless

> Get your free quote Now!

Comment: The marked duplicate is about capitalization in user-interface components, whereas this question seems to be more about Random Capitalization in body text. Not sure if that warrants re-opening, but there may be better dupe-targets. Some possibly more related questions: [Do capital letters make you seem serious?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/92592/57088), [(How) does capitalization affect readability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/67454/57088) and (to a lesser degree) [All Caps vs Bold](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/110132/57088).